# Localizacion de includes en C

Tags: c, atmel

Estoy programando en el IDE de Atmel Studio en C y cuando intento incluir estas librerías

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
```

al utilizar sus métodos y después compilar no me las localiza, como si no existieran. ¿Dónde las puedo encontrar?

Comment: Hola, ¿qué error te sale? Puede que te falte alguna dependencia

Comment: El PC donde estás programando es windows o linux?

Comment: programando en Windows

Comment: Sergio, por favor agrega el error que da el precompilador para que sepamos como ayudarte. gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Primero acláranos (o aclárate) qué te están faltando concretamente.

> intento incluir estas librerías

Esas nos son librerías, esos son C headers (includes) que solo  sirven para declarar constantes y funciones (no "métodos").

> sus métodos y después compilar no me las localiza, como si no existieran

Es imposible entender lo que te pasa. Te arroja un error de que no encuentra uno de los ".h" incluidos (cuáles?)? O te arroja un error de al compilar no encuentra la declaración de una función que debería estar en uno de los includes? O te tira un error de linkeo de que no encuentra la implementación de una función en una librería? Son tres cosas absolutamente distintas, y tu descripción del problema es muy vaga.

Si no tienes claro estas cosas, deberías primero tratar de hacer andar un programa muy simple (hola mundo)...

Answer (score -1):

`Atmel` es un compilador para crear aplicaciones para pequeños dispositivos que no son PC.

No tienes las librería de sistema dado que no tienes un sistema al uso.

Si quieres compilar para PC, mejor usa otros compiladores e IDE's (los hay cientos : MSVC, CodeBlocks, gcc , mingw, etc etc etc)

Si quieres compilar para dispositivos Atmel, tendrás que buscar otras librerias que hagan lo que quieres, por que las típicas no te van a funcionar.

Comment: La pregunta especifica que está usando el  Atmel Studio en C , no sé por qué le recomiendas que uses otros compiladores.

Comment: Desconozco si realmente está programando para arquitectura Atmel o si realmente quiere programar para arquitectura x86. No sería la primera vez que veo usar compiladores de arquitecturas especificas para generar ejecutables de PC. La etiqueta Atmel la puse yo para que más gente conocedora del tema pudiera dar una respuesta más certera que la mía, originalmente solo había la etiqueta de C.